# How do I retrieve a value from a list of objects in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I've been spinning my wheels on this for a while. I have made my api call and successfully returned the data I'm looking for. I have taken this data and inserted it into a database. I've verified all of the info I need is in the database through the database inspector. Now I am looking to retrieve the data from the database, and populate a spinner with that data. Specifically I'm looking to retrieve a list of colors from SeedColors

```
    @Entity(tableName = "colors")
data class SeedColors(
    @PrimaryKey
    val colorSeedID: String,
    val color: String,
    val timeCreated: String,
    val timeUpdated: String,
    val type: String
)
```

Here is my dao interface

```
interface DogColorDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM colors")
    fun getAll(): Flow<List<SeedColors>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM colors")
    fun getAllColors(): List<SeedColors>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM colors WHERE colorSeedID = :colorID")
    fun getColorById(colorID: Int): SeedColors

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertDogColors(dogColor: List<SeedColors>)

    @Delete
    fun deleteAll(colors: SeedColors)
```

Repository:

```
       val db: DogColorDatabase = DogColorDatabase.getDatabase(MatchbreedApp.ctx)
    
        val allColors: Flow<List<SeedColors>> = db.dogColorDao().getAll()
```

ViewModel:

```
class SeedViewModel(private val repo: SeedRepo): ViewModel() {

    val errorData: MutableLiveData<ErrorObject> = MutableLiveData()

    
    // access room here
    val allColors: LiveData<List<SeedColors>> = repo.allColors.asLiveData()
    val allBreeds: LiveData<List<SeedBreed>> = repo.allBreeds.asLiveData()
    val elbows: LiveData<List<Elbow>> = repo.elbows.asLiveData()
    val heart: LiveData<List<Heart>> = repo.heart.asLiveData()
    val hips: LiveData<List<Hip>> = repo.hips.asLiveData()
    val temperament: LiveData<List<Temperament>> = repo.temperament.asLiveData()
    val policies: LiveData<List<SeedPolicies>> = repo.policies.asLiveData()
    val externalLinks: LiveData<List<ExternalLinks>> = repo.externalLinks.asLiveData()
    val titles: LiveData<List<SeedTitle>> = repo.titles.asLiveData()

    fun getSeeds() {
        repo.getSeeds("all", getStringPref(PREF_TOKEN), "", errorData)
    }
```

custom spinner adapter:

```
class MBColorSpinnerAdapter(var context: Context, var colorList: List<SeedColors>): BaseAdapter() {

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return colorList.size
    }

    override fun getItem(i: Int): Any {
        return i
    }

    override fun getItemId(i: Int): Long {
        return i.toLong()
    }

    override fun getView(i: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val view: View
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        //LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.mb_spinner_item, parent, false)
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mb_spinner_item, parent, false)
        val viewHolder: MBColorSpinnerAdapter.ItemHolder = ItemHolder(view)
        view?.tag = viewHolder

        viewHolder.color.text = colorList[i].color

        return view
    }

    override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val view: View = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent)
        val textView: TextView = view as TextView
        if (position == 0) {
            textView.text = ""
        }
        return view
    }

    override fun isEnabled(position: Int): Boolean {

        return position != 0
    }

    fun updateColorList(colors: List<SeedColors>) {
        this.colorList = colors
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class ItemHolder(view: View?) {
        var color: TextView = view?.findViewById(R.id.spinner_drop_down) as TextView
    }
}
```

And in my fragment, I am observing changes to the database and updating the adapter

initializing the adapter with an empty arrayList

```
    private fun initSpinners() {
        breedSpinner = _binding.sBreed
        colorSpinner = _binding.sColor
        colorAdapter = MBColorSpinnerAdapter(requireContext(), dogColorList)
        breedAdapter = MBSpinnerAdapter(
            requireContext(),
            breedList
        )

        if (seedViewModel.allColors.hasActiveObservers()) {
            seedViewModel.allColors.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, colorObserver)
            colorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
```

and here is my observer

```
private val colorObserver: Observer<List<SeedColors>> = Observer {
        if (it != null) {
            colorAdapter.updateColorList(it)
        }
    }
```

what I think is happening is that I am setting the adapter to the whole SeedColor object, and it doesn't know what to choose - color, type, colorSeedID, etc. I'm trying to figure out a way to get the object values that I want (color) into a list and populate my adapter with that instead of a List. But I'm not sure how to do that. I've seen a lot of

```
var color: List<String> = allColors.map {
    it.color
}
```

but that isn't working because it's still in a list. I can do

```
var color: List<String> = allColors.map {
   it[0].color
}
```

but this only gives me 1 color, and there's over 100. any ideas??

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Currently retrieving information just like it should. Would be helpful if I set my adapter. that was the issue why nothing was populating the spinner.

```
colorSpinner.adapter = colorAdapter
```